# How to shutdown redis safely without data loss

Tags: redis, centos, shutdown, persist

I have written a script which can get really long to run, I save the steps that are passed in the redis because it's fast and has almost no overhead, but a manual reboot or a server downtime could happen in the middle, so if the last step isn't saved the whole process will have to start from the beginning!

Ideally I want to set up redis in a way, that it persists before shutdown, (if this is not already supported by default which I couldn't find anything about it) in the basic way I would need to be able to persist the data with redis-cli or anyway possible via a script, then find a way to run a script before shutdown of CentOS.

So any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis features different [persistence options](https://redis.io/docs/manual/persistence/), including AOF (Append Only File) that

> logs every write operation received by the server, that will be played again at server startup, reconstructing the original dataset

with the ability to *fsync* at every query.

If this is not a viable option for you, you may want to issue a combination of [`BGSAVE`](https://redis.io/commands/bgsave/) and [`LASTSAVE`](https://redis.io/commands/lastsave/) commands in order to start an asynchronous saving process and check whether the last saving completed successfully or not.